# What wrong with my code "Filling up the text box depending to the value of a combo box"??

Tags: vb.net

I have a combo box that have a value of "Internet, Games, print (short), print (long)"... All I want is if I choose Internet in the combo box the text box "t_amount" should populate as "20"

here's my code...

```
Private Sub C_job_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles C_job.SelectedIndexChanged
    If C_job.SelectedIndex = "Internet" Then
        t_amount.Text = "20"
    ElseIf C_job.SelectedIndex = "Games" Then
        t_amount.Text = "10"
    ElseIf C_job.SelectedIndex = "Print (short)" Then
        t_amount.Text = "1"
    ElseIf C_job.SelectedIndex = "Print (long)" Then
        t_amount.Text = "2"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SelectedIndex` property returns an *index*, which is a number. Not a string. The first item in the combobox will have an index of 0, the next item an index of 1, etc.

Or, to get a string, use `SelectedItem.ToString()`:

```
Private Sub C_job_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles C_job.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim selected As String = C_job.SelectedItem.ToString()

    If selected  = "Internet" Then
        t_amount.Text = "20"
    ElseIf selected = "Games" Then
        t_amount.Text = "10"
    ElseIf selected = "Print (short)" Then
        t_amount.Text = "1"
    ElseI fselected = "Print (long)" Then
        t_amount.Text = "2"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert, but think you should be using "selected value" changed, or if using the index then this is a numeric index, i.e. "internet" would be index number 0.

HTH

Comment: ah...I tried it already...I changed the  SelectedIndex to SelectedValue. But there's nothing populate in the textbox..

Comment: just checking, did you change both SelectedIndex as follows: Private Sub C_job_SelectedValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles C_job.SelectedValueChanged

Comment: yup here the code `Private Sub C_job_SelectedValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles C_job.SelectedValueChanged
        If C_job.SelectedValue = "Internet" Then
            t_amount.Text = "20"
        ElseIf C_job.SelectedValue = "Games" Then
            t_amount.Text = "10"
        ElseIf C_job.SelectedValue = "Print (short)" Then
            t_amount.Text = "1"
        ElseIf C_job.SelectedValue = "Print (long)" Then
            t_amount.Text = "2"
        End If
    End Sub`

Comment: codygray has got it nailed i think.

Answer (score 0):

You already have an answer, but I think the code can be improved upon a little.  As a rule of thumb, if I'm going to be doing a check against a single variable for more than a couple items in a list, I use `Select Case` rather than an ongoing list of `ElseIf` statements.  The number one reason being that if you change something on the first one, you'll have to remember to change it on all the others.  CodeGray has solved some of this issue by declaring the value as a local variable, but the readability still stands to gain, so try this instead:

```
Select Case C_job.SelectedItem.ToString
    Case "Internet"
        t_amount.Text = "20"
    Case "Games"
        t_amount.Text = "10"
    Case "Print (short)"
        t_amount.Text = "1"
    Case "Print (long)"
        t_amount.Text = "2"
End Select
```

Also, i just wanted to check that you were using the `Display Member` and the `Value Member` of the ComboBox correctly.  You can expose two properties with native support in combo boxes, one a value to display to the user, and a second a backing property.  When you're executing code, you'll have access to both.  The plus side is you can store this information in a more declarative way and then react accordingly.

When the ComboBox has a selection, that information is stored in the `SelectedItem` property which stores the original object used to populate that drop down item.  If you've defined a `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` for combo box items, then the `SelectedText` and `SelectedValue` will expose just those properties for the selected object.

Here's the **Setup**

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim dataSource As New DataTable

    With dataSource.Columns
        .Add("Display", GetType(String))
        .Add("Value", GetType(Integer))
    End With

    With dataSource.Rows
        .Add("Internet", 20)
        .Add("Games", 10)
        .Add("Print (short)", 1)
        .Add("Print (long)", 2)
    End With

    With C_job
        .DisplayMember = "Display"
        .ValueMember = "Value"
        .DataSource = dataSource
    End With
End Sub
```

The plus side, is now here's all the code you need to handle the event

```
Private Sub C_job_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles C_job.SelectedIndexChanged
    t_amount.Text = C_job.SelectedValue
End Sub
```

If you wanted to, this will also make binding this property very easy since you've coded all your logic upfront.